# Upload Image directly to <img> tag without sending it to the Server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have an upload form:

```
<form>
  <input accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" type="file" name="image" id="image" class="UploadInput" onchange="submitImageUploaderForm()"/>
</form>
```

Using this form the image is sent to the server. At my server I can send the image back to the   browser and insert it into a  tag as preview image.

What I need is the following:

1. upload an image to the users browser (without the way to the server)
2. processing the image in the browser
3. send the result image to the server

How can I do that?

Comment: Any solution for previewing an image without using the serverside will use the HTML5 File API, which is not supported in IE9, so in other words what you're trying to do can't be done, at least not with the browser support you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [File API](http://caniuse.com/fileapi) which is not supported by IE9. No luck